# how to set mpdf HTML contains invalid UTF-8 character(s)

Tags: php, pdf

how to set mpdf HTML contains invalid UTF-8 character(s) when you create pdf on your appliactions

Comment: What are you asking for? What have you tried? What happens then?

Answer (score 40):

Try this

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

before calling: *"$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);"*

It's seems senseless, but it works for me.

Comment: Worked for me - thats nuts

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me as well. allow_charset_conversion didn't do anything for me..

Comment: I had this error: "Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfException: Invalid input characters. Did you set $mpdf->in_charset properly?"
and this solution solved it.

Answer (score 7):

With mpdf it is no point in conversions and encoding as these most likely will lose your chars and you would get only "?" or other unrecognisable chars (but will yield output)

Try using these before any input being send to mpdf:

```
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion=true;
$mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8';
```

Comment: I have `&copy;` in a footer which was executing as normal text. This solved the problem perfectly.

Comment: @Runa  i have the problem with two char '??'
this solve my problem :

  **$output= utf8_encode($output);**

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_encode($html));
```

Answer (score 4):

The below two lines will do the trick

```
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in = 'iso-8859-4';
```

Add the above two lines after creating the object , this will look like

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in = 'iso-8859-4';
```

Comment: this is the only one that would work for me...  i also had to install iconv on php.  the other one $mpdf->charset_in = 'utf-8';  didn't do it for me.

Comment: This worked for me. It is good to also note that 'iso-8859-4' should be replaced with whatever character set your html is using otherwise it may not work for your html.

Answer (score 3):

Use utf8_encode() function.
Eg :
$html = '

Name of Originator

Originator Address

Originator Phone Number

Originator Email

Borrower

Property Address

Date of GFE

Â

';
$html = utf8_encode($html1);

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

> Use
>
> autoScriptToLang = true;
> autoLangToFont   = true;

```
    include("mpdf-6.0.0/mpdf.php");
    $mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    
    $mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
    $mpdf->autoLangToFont   = true;

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output('SavePDF.pdf', 'D');
```

Answer (score 1):

After hours of hair-pulling, this worked wonders for me :)

(In my case बोटोक्स was showing as ??????)

**$mpdf->SetAutoFont();**

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8','', 0, '', 15, 15, 16, 16, 9, 9, 'L');
$mpdf->SetAutoFont();

//~ Nothing of below worked :(
//~ $mpdf->useLang = true;
//~ $mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
//~ $mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
//~ $pdf_html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
//~ $mpdf->DeletePages(2);
$filename   = date('ymdhis').".pdf";
$mpdf->Output($filename,'D');
```

My PDF included a mix of English and Hindi words like

"3 units of बोटोक्स Priced @ $10.00/unit".

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I send `NULL` to `->multicell()`. Sending `""` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% sure that problem is because you did some manipulations with the text using unicode-unsafe functions. Use `mb_strpos()/mb_substr()` instead of `strpos()/substr()`, and add "`/u`" modifier to all your conversions with `prog_replace()`.

Of course, the problem can be fixed by allowing "charset conversion" as already suggested before. But much better to know that your text already correct and meets the compliance of UTF-8.