# Korea currency symbol is not showing in yii2 mpdf

Tags: php, pdf, yii2, mpdf

i am showing Korea currency symbol in yii2 mpdf but it is showing an imoge icon. please help me to fix this issue my currencyHTMLCode is "&#8361" and shor name is KRW.
and i am doing to show this inside the pdf.
code:-

```
        <span style="font-size:250%; margin-right : 10px"><?php echo  $currency_html_code;?></span>
```

where $currency_html_code = "&#8361"

Comment: It's probably an encoding issue. Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736061/how-to-set-mpdf-html-contains-invalid-utf-8-characters

Comment: Does this solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63736642/mpdf-php-library-do-not-show-pound-currency-sign-%C2%A3

Comment: No. i used     "<span style='font-family: DejaVu Sans; sans-serif;'>".$currencyHtmlCode."</span>" this code solved my probled

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display currency symbol on yii2 mpdf. you can use this line of code for the currency symbol. mostly KOREA and INDIAN currency having this type of issue. Here currencyHtmlCode can we currency code like `"&#8361"`

```
"<span style='font-family: DejaVu Sans; sans-serif;'>".currencyHtmlCode."</span>"
```